# Using SwingWorker and Timer to display time on a label?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, javax.swing.timer

I want to have a clock showing current time and refreshes every second. The code I am using is:

```
int timeDelay = 1000;
ActionListener time;
time = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            timeLabel.setText(DateTimeUtil.getTime()); 
            /*timeLabel is a JLabel to display time,
            getTime() is samll static methos to return formatted String of current time */
        }
    };
SwingWorker timeWorker = new SwingWorker() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            new Timer(timeDelay, time).start();
            return null;
        }
    };
timeWorker.execute();
```

What I want to refresh the `timeLabel` text in another thread other than EDT.
Am I doing it correct? Any other better way?
Also for information, i've added `timeLabel` to a *`extended`*`JPanel` which contains few similar kinds of utilities, and is called in another *`Main`*`JFrame`.

Comment: In addition to the excellent advice from @Jonas (1+), one thing that you're doing wrong is making Swing calls from within a background thread. SwingWorker's `doInBackground()` method should contain no Swing calls that cannot be called on a background thread, meaning that you should most definitely not create a Swing Timer inside of this method, nor call `start()` on a Swing Timer object here.

Comment: +1 for this advice. Thank You. One more thing is, `doInBackground()` cannot contain Swing calls - is that mean I should not initializes swing components inside frame like panels, buttons etc via `SwingWorker`?

Comment: Absolutely correct. SwingWorker is for non-Swing initialization and for communication with Swing via publish, process, and done methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this without a SwingWorker, because this is what the Swing Timer is made for.

```
int timeDelay = 1000;
ActionListener time;
time = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        timeLabel.setText(DateTimeUtil.getTime()); 
        /* timeLabel is a JLabel to display time,
           getTime() is samll static methos to return 
           formatted String of current time */
    }
};

new Timer(timeDelay, time).start();
```

Comment: Is the Actions in swing Timer is itself start in a different thread??

Comment: @Asif: The action is executed on the EDT, because alla GUI modifications most be made from the EDT.

Comment: @Asif: Conversely, the timer's `delay` happens on a different thread.